# Can't get indexing for Header Column with Pandas

Tags: python, django, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to resonate excel file with Panda's data representation in Django templates. I've tried quite a few things but I can't get header columns indexed as 1. Pandas starts indexing below the header columns. If will be great help if someone can guide me. Below is the code I am trying to resonate with Excel sheet exactly.

```
def home(request):
template = 'home.html'
form = ExcelUpload(request.POST or None, request.FILES)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        excelfile = ExcelFileUpload(uploaded_file = request.FILES['uploaded_file'])
        excelfile.save()
        data = pd.read_excel(excelfile.uploaded_file.path, header=None)
        new_header = data.iloc[0]
        data = data[1:]
        data.columns = new_header
        data_to_html = data.to_html
        return render(request, template, {'form':form, 'data_to_html':data_to_html})
else:
    form = ExcelUpload()
return render(request, template, {'form': form})
```

My excel file shows 20 entries indexed in the [image] but when I parse it to web it shows me 19 entries indexed like this [image]. I need help to convert headers into index 1 so my excel file and web sheet resonates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a df with default index (starting at 0), then removing the first row (now index of first row is 1). That is why it is shown like that.

Try:

```
data = data[1:].reindex(range(2, len(data)+1))
```

Comment: I kind of tried that before something similar. It does not show index 1 at header row. But it does starts from "2" for below rows. You can try it with the piece of code. Its all in one django view. Thanks for the kind effort though. :-)